# Does hdmi_cvt need the '=' in config.txt?

Tags: config.txt

I've got an HDMI touchscreen for my Raspberry Pi, and the instructions say to add the following to the end of the `config.txt` file:

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
```

The documentation at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md says that `hdmi_cvt` takes `=`:

```
hdmi_cvt=<width> <height> <framerate> <aspect> <margins> <interlace> <rb>
```

I've found examples of both on the Internet and on this site.

Which is correct?

Comment: By the way you should only have one 'hdmi_mode' entry.

Comment: @Dirk, because I can't get the screen working (it works fine plugged into a laptop, and it works fine with `hdmi_safe=1`), and I'm trying to work out whether the instructions are wrong, or if I'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: Add a link to the screen.

Comment: `because I can't get the screen working` well, logic tells me that it only takes 2 boots. If both don't work then the rest of the line has an error and it's irrelevant if you need the equal sign or not.

Comment: So you have an answer below: both work. Time to solve the real problem :)

Answer (score 6):

I've just tested this on my Pi3 with 5 inch touchscreen - both work - with and without the '='.

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt=800 480 60 6 0 0 0
```

Worked

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
```

Worked